# Application of the study of equations over finite fields

Tags: abstract-algebra, algebraic-geometry, polynomials, algebraic-number-theory, finite-fields

I’m currently studying equations over finite fields (in particular solutions over $F_{q^k}$ to  equations of the form $y^q-y=f(X)$ for a polynomial $f(X) \in F_q[X]$) and approximations of the number of their solutions.
In the above case (with N being the number of solutions $(x,y) \in (F_{q^k})^2$ to $y^q-y=f(X)$) we know that $|N-q^k|<q^{[\frac{k}{2}]+4}$.

I am wondering now, how those results, that we find, can be applied (e.g. in computer science). Why are we even studying those equations? Can someone provide me with an example of an application?

Thank you a lot in advance!

Comment: Give me a couple of hours to lecture, and I will try and convince you that GPS works because we have a good bound for $|N-2^{10}|$, $q=2$, $k=10$ and every cubic polynomial $f(x)$. Basically that gives us the tools to A) distinguish the signal from different satellites and, B) to get that accurate time drift of the signal from a satellite we track. Given the time differences and positions of the satellites, a "banal" exercise in analytic geometry allows us to track the position of the GPS receiver.

Comment: Ok, I don't have those hours, so you have to settle with [WP](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gold_code).

Comment: @JyrkiLahtonen thank you a lot for that insight! Do you maybe then know a concise article, that explains the basics of it?

Comment: oh I just saw the link, thank you!

Answer (score 3):

There is a class of error-correcting codes called "algebraic geometry codes". The parameters for these codes depend on the number of solutions of equations over finite fields. https://arxiv.org/pdf/1505.03020.pdf claims to be an introductory paper on the topic.

Comment: oh okay, I'll try and read through it to get some overview, thank you!!

Answer (score 2):

**Question:** "I am wondering now, how those results, that we find, can be applied (e.g. in computer science)."

**Answer:** Studying algebraic curves over finite fields has applications in the field "cryptography":

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Elliptic-curve_cryptography

**Example:** In Hartshorne (HH), Exercise AppC.5.6 and 5.7 they prove the Weil conjectures for elliptic curves. Section IV in the same book studies curves in general. Fulton's "Algebraic curves" is a more elementary introduction to the theory of algebraic curves. Note that in positive characteristic you will need much of the machinery introduced in HH.

In algebra/geometry the study of algebraic varieties over a finite field is much studied. This study goes all the way back to 1800BC.

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Weil_conjectures

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Algebraic_number_theory#Diophantus

Comment: thank you, that is already really helpful! I am preparing a talk on that topic (the mathematical side to it, not the application) and was wondering if you maybe knew a catchy example to start off with, as an introduction, to see how what we are doing can be useful later

Comment: oh and maybe, could you explain a little more about the use in algebra/ geometry? Why exactly study $y^d-y=f(x)$, have the approximations of the number of solutions of those equations been used to prove other theorems? Or why are they of relevance, what is the larger context? I would be really thankful to get some more insight, thank you a lot for your help already!:) @hm2020